# Barra de rolagem em um select

Tags: html

Como por uma barra de rolagem um "scroll" para rolar em um select ? Por exemplo:

```
<select>
  <option>a</option>
  <option>b</option>
  <option>c</option>
  <option>d</option>
  <option>e</option>
  <option>f</option>
  <option>g</option>
</select>
```

Tem como por um scroll para a caixa que desce não ficar muito grande ? Enves de listar todos abaixo apenas 3 e depois poder ir rolando para baixo.

Comment: Já tentou `size="3"`? ah se for pra selecionar mais de um coloque `multiple`

Comment: Você já tentou usar o plugin bootstrap select ?

Comment: Não, estou usando o foundation como framework.

Comment: Ele tem um recurso interessante para isso, você pode dar uma olhada nele. 
https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

Comment: @Duque Põe como resposta então.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select{
   overflow-y:auto;
}

<select size='3'>
  <option>a</option>
  <option>b</option>
  <option>c</option>
  <option>d</option>
  <option>e</option>
  <option>f</option>
  <option>g</option>
</select>
```

ATUALIZANDO

Você pode usar o plugin bootstrap select, pelo o que entendi, você quer controlar o height da caixa que abre quando clica no select.
Bootstrap select tem esse recurso, veja:

O atributo usado é o `data-size`

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-size="2">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

Exemplo rodando aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/aduque/zs2g2re3/

Bootstrap select possui dependências, são elas: Jquery e Bootstrap

Espero que agora resolva seu problema.

Comment: "Para a caixa que desce", ele disse, ou seja, para a drop down list, então essa solução não resolve.

Comment: Entendi jhonny, não havia entendido bem o que ele queria dizer.